# In Material UI, How can I override a selector selected component style?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-admin, jss

In Material UI, to extend the distance between `MuiInputLabel` and `MuiInput`, I have to override the marginTop of `label + .MuiInput-formControl`.

However, `createMuiTheme`'s override only provide direct override of a Mui Component CSS, such as:

```js
createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiInput: {
      formControl: {
        marginTop: '1.5rem',
      },
    },
  }
})
```

How can I do something like:

```js
createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    'label+MuiInput': {
      formControl: {
        marginTop: '1.5rem',
      },
    },
  }
})
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's the relevant JSS documentation:

https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-nested?v=v10.0.0-alpha.10#use--to-reference-selector-of-the-parent-rule

Here's the syntax you need:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiInput: {
      formControl: {
        "label + &": {
          marginTop: "1.5rem"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Here's a working example:

[image: Edit 24v1wr9x0n]