# Simple selector and nested selector in JSS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

I'm currently training on ReactJS. I'm using material-ui and JSS (totally new for me).

I don't understand how can I simply select my H6 element or my H6 children elements (dangerStyle).

Any idea ?

Thanks !

myJss.js

```
const myJss = theme => ({
    textCenter : {
        textAlign:'center'
    },
    dangerStyle: {
        fontWeight:'normal',
        color:"#FF0000"
    },
    h6: {
        color:"#00FF00",
        "&.dangerStyle" : {
            fontWeight:'bold',
        }
    }

});
export default myJss;
```

app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Danger from 'components/danger'
import myJss from 'assets/jss/myJss.js';

class App extends Component {

    constructor (props) {
        super(props)
    }

    render () {
        const { classes } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                APP
                <h6>
                    <Danger>Error occured</Danger>
                </h6>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default withStyles(myJss)(App)
```

danger.js

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import myJss from 'assets/jss/myJss.js';
const useStyles = makeStyles(myJss);

export default function Danger(props) {
    const { children } = props;
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <div className={classes.dangerStyle}>
            {children}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: what css does that output?  Do you see a `h6 .dangerStyle` entry?   If so, then you should just be able to do `<div className="dangerStyle">`

Comment: @DavinTryon : Jss compilated with makeStyles. h6 .dangerStyle cannot work.

Answer (score 3):

Each key in your styles object is going to be used to generate a CSS class. A key like `h6` does not target the `h6` tag, it just allows you to reference `classes.h6` as a class similar to `classes.dangerStyle`.

In order to have the `dangerStyle` class behave differently when nested within an `h6` tag, you can do something like the following:

**Danger.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  dangerStyle: {
    fontWeight: "normal",
    color: "#FF0000",
    "h6 &": {
      color: "#00FF00",
      fontWeight: "bold",
      fontSize: 24
    }
  }
});

export default function Danger(props) {
  const { children } = props;
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <div className={classes.dangerStyle}>{children}</div>;
}
```

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import Danger from "./Danger";
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Danger>Danger not in h6</Danger>
      <h6>
        <Danger>Danger in h6</Danger>
      </h6>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit JSS nested rule]

Related answers and documentation:

- [jss-plugin-nested documentation](https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-nested/?v=v10.0.0-alpha.24#use--to-reference-selector-of-the-parent-rule)
- [Using material ui createStyles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57871809/using-material-ui-createstyles/57873871#57873871)
- [Advanced styling in material-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58019444/advanced-styling-in-material-ui/58019642#58019642)
- [In Material UI, How can I override a selector selected component style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54724968/in-material-ui-how-can-i-override-a-selector-selected-component-style/54726562#54726562)
- [how to use css in JS for nested hover styles, Material UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57716926/how-to-use-css-in-js-for-nested-hover-styles-material-ui/57729101#57729101)
- [Using createMuiTheme to override default styles on div's, p's, body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56448538/using-createmuitheme-to-override-default-styles-on-divs-ps-body/56450285#56450285)

Comment: Thanks ! The "h6 &" was the solution. It changes when you are used to CSS... It's the only existing solution ? And how can I target a simple html tag (h1, ... , h6, p, etc...) with JSS (except to add a specific class...) ?

Comment: In general, the idea with JSS is to avoid having any global styles (which is what you have if you target tags directly), but it does support global styles: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56448538/using-createmuitheme-to-override-default-styles-on-divs-ps-body/56450285#56450285

Comment: Ok, @global is the solution ... And I note to avoid having any global styles :) Thanks a lot !

Comment: Usually it's the parent that has the "context" which cascades to the child. In this case the child is bound the parent. `h6.dangerChild ELEMENT` where `ELEMENT` knows nothing about its ancestors (as it should) seems to be a better architectural approach. This does not seem possible. Is it?

Answer (score 0):

implement `CSS` nested rules in `JSS`

```
'& $selector'
```

for example:

```
'&$dangerStyle' : {
  fontWeight:'bold',
}
```